# Tomcat webapps folder gets wiped out after computer restart

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, fedora

I have tomcat installed on a linux box. I deploy my services, restart tomcat, and everything works great. But after I restart my computer, the services (war files) get deleted automatically from the webapps folder. Has anyone encountered this issue, and knows a solution?

Comment: which directory are they located in? Hopefully not some tmp filesystem? What are the permissions on those files?

Comment: @OlafKock The war files get downloaded to the TOMCAT_HOME/webapps folder. They have root permissions.